# JDeveloper Webservice Deployment Error:

Tags: web-services, deployment, weblogic, jdeveloper

I have run into an interesting error. I have created a PL/SQL Webservice in JDeveloper. I can run/deploy it successfully on the integrated WebLogic Server that runs in JDeveloper, but cannot deploy the web service to a live WebLogic server.

I get the following error when I try to deploy to a live weblogic server (this weblogic server has JRF, JRF Webservices, and JAX-RPC runtimes installed):

> "Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error looking up java:comp/env/jdbc/local_orcl_hrDS".

The JDBC connnection name in JDeveloper is local_orcl_hr, I even created a JDBC connection name with the full path specified in the error and a JDBC connection with the name "local_orcl_hrDS". I get the same error. The error tells me that it can't find the datasource on the server but it exists. On WebLogic all changes have been activated and the database connections test successfully.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you!

Full trace:

> java.sql.SQLException: Error looking up : 
>       at local_orcl_hr.DeptService1Base.(DeptService1Base.java:33)
>       at local_orcl_hr.DeptService1User.(DeptService1User.java:11)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
>       at weblogic.wsee.component.pojo.JavaClassComponent.createTarget(JavaClassComponent.java:49)
>       at weblogic.wsee.component.pojo.JavaClassComponent.(JavaClassComponent.java:40)
>       at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.setComponent(WsBuilder.java:1907)
>       at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsBuilder.buildService(WsBuilder.java:215)
>       at weblogic.wsee.ws.WsFactory.createServerService(WsFactory.java:54)
>       at weblogic.wsee.deploy.ServletDeployInfo.createWsService(ServletDeployInfo.java:91)
>       at weblogic.wsee.deploy.DeployInfo.createWsPort(DeployInfo.java:372)
>       at weblogic.wsee.server.servlet.BaseWSServlet.init(BaseWSServlet.java:83)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
>       at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>       at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1976)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1950)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1869)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3126)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1512)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:486)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:1267)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:409)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
>       at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
>       at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
>       at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
>       at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

[02:47:28 PM] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error looking up : 
[02:47:28 PM]   See server logs or server console for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems.

1. In my JDBC configuration I needed, "jcbc/local_orcl_hr" for my jndi name
2. Once I did the above changes, deploying still failed. However the deployment made it to the server, so I went onto the WebLogic Administrator > Deployments > selected my deployment > clicked update. Then I redeployed from the war file used, and everything worked!